# Can't draw shape when I press a key in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, glut

I'm having a problem when I draw some shapes. When I execute the program I should only see the coordinates, and then after pressing a key to draw the shape, but by default it is already drawn the cube and after this the pyramid. How can I do to draw the pyramid when I press 'p' key and cube when I press 'c'? I tried something but it seems that it's not working :(

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "dependente\freeglut\freeglut.h"
#include "dependente\glfw\glfw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define  RADDEG  57.29577951f

float XUP[3] = { 1,0,0 }, XUN[3] = { -1, 0, 0 },
YUP[3] = { 0,1,0 }, YUN[3] = { 0,-1, 0 },
ZUP[3] = { 0,0,1 }, ZUN[3] = { 0, 0,-1 },
ORG[3] = { 0,0,0 };

GLfloat viewangle = 0, tippangle = 0, traj[120][3];

GLfloat d[3] = { 0.1, 0.1, 0.1 };

GLfloat  xAngle = 0.0, yAngle = 0.0, zAngle = 0.0;

//  Use arrow keys to rotate entire scene !!!

void Special_Keys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {

    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:  viewangle -= 5;  break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:  viewangle += 5;  break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:  tippangle -= 5;  break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  tippangle += 5;  break;

    default: printf("Special key %c == %d", key, key);
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void Pyramid(void) //draw the pyramid shape
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //V0(red)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);   //V1(green)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);   //V2(blue)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);   //V3(green)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);   //V4(blue)
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);   //V1(green)
    glEnd();
}

void Draw_Box(void)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.7, 0.1);     // Front - green
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glColor3f(0.9, 1.0, 0.0);    // Back  - yellow
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

    glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 1.0);     // Top - blue 
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0);

    glColor3f(0.7, 0.0, 0.1);    // Bottom - red
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, -1.0, -1.0);
    glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

    glEnd();
}

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) //press a key to perform actions
{
    switch (key) {

    case 'd': d[0] += 0.1;  break;
    case 'a': d[0] -= 0.1;  break;
    case 'w': d[1] += 0.1;  break;
    case 's': d[1] -= 0.1;  break;
    case 'm': d[2] += 0.1;  break;
    case 'n': d[2] -= 0.1;  break;
    case 'p': Pyramid();  break;
    case 'c': Draw_Box();  break;

    case 'x': xAngle += 5;  break;
    case 'y': yAngle += 5;  break;
    case 'z': zAngle += 5;  break;

    default: printf("   Keyboard %c == %d", key, key);
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}



void Triad(void)
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //set the dark grey color 

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3fv(ORG); glVertex3fv(XUP);
    glVertex3fv(ORG); glVertex3fv(YUP);
    glVertex3fv(ORG); glVertex3fv(ZUP);
    glEnd();

    glRasterPos3f(1.1, 0.0, 0.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, 'X'); //draw the x axis

    glRasterPos3f(0.0, 1.1, 0.0);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, 'Y'); //draw the y axis

    glRasterPos3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.1);
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, 'Z'); //draw the z axis 
}






void redraw(void)
{
    int v;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);
    glRotatef(tippangle, 1, 0, 0);  // Up and down arrow keys 'tip' view.
    glRotatef(viewangle, 0, 1, 0);  // Right/left arrow keys 'turn' view.

    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    Triad();


    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(d[0], d[1], d[2]);    // Move box down X axis.
    glScalef(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    glRotatef(zAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    glRotatef(yAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(xAngle, 1, 0, 0);
    //Draw_Box(); // if i delete comment the cube it's drawn
    //Pyramid(); // if i delete this the pyramid it's drawn inside the cube
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//---+----3----+----2----+----1----+---<>---+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 300);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutCreateWindow("Big HW1");
    glutDisplayFunc(redraw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(Special_Keys);

    glClearColor(0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(60, 1.5, 1, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your `redraw` function clears the screen, so instead of drawing the cube and pyramid in your keyboard handler, set a flag like `drawPyramid` or `drawCube` and check for that in your `redraw` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve that. One is to create a global variable that will tell you if you want to draw the shapes or not:

```
bool draw_pyramid = false;
bool draw_box = false;
```

Then, in you keyboard handle function, do this:

```
case 'p': draw_pyramid = true;  break;
case 'c': draw_box = true;  break;
```

and finally, at your redraw function, do a conditional draw:

```
if ( draw_pyramid )
    Pyramid();

if ( draw_box )
    Draw_Box();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked <3 but it has a little problem...it draws the shape one over another...:( how can I erase the current shape when I press a key?

Comment: By unsetting the other flag, or using a single variable to determine what to draw.

Comment: You can try, for example: `case 'p': draw_pyramid = true; draw_box = false; break;`

Comment: Yep, it worked, thank you very much, inspiration it's very low today for me, this seems to be a easy thing...